# Find links and make them clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm developing a chat with socketio. Each time a message is sent, I display it using this very simple jquery:

```
            $('#try').prepend(my_message);
```

with:

```
            <div id='try'></div>
```

What I would like to do is to find if the message posted contains a link and if so make it clickable. I need to find either http:// and www.

I found several question related, but none of them gave me the solution I'm looking for.

Any idea on how I can accomplish that?

Comment: Isn't the link clickable by default?

Comment: should div have a class? <div class="try"></div>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for every new message inserted in your chat do something like

```
var conversation = "This message contains a link to http://www.google.com "
                 + "and another to www.stackoverflow.com";

conversation = conversation.replace(/(www\..+?)(\s|$)/g, function(text, link) {
   return '<a href="http://'+ link +'">'+ link +'</a>';
})



/**
 *  output :
 *  This message contains a link to <a href="http://www.google.com">http:
 *  //www.google.com</a>and another to <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">   
 *  www.stackoverflow.com</a>
 */
```

then re-append the new message into your chat.

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly for urls beginning with http. How could I make it works for links beginning with www?

Comment: @Marcolac see my update, otherwise choose a more accurate regular expression for link detection

Comment: Ok, I meant how to replace both www and http://. But I guess I just have to add both functions. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 9):

You should use a regex expression to replace all http/https links to anchor tags:

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
}
```

For more information you can take a look at [How to replace plain URLs with links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links) and [Coding Horror: The Problem with URLs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-problem-with-urls.html). Hope this helps.